# How to add more than 1 condition when using LINQ-to-DataSet with Enumerable.Any() in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I tried to check if values exist in dataTable.

With code:

```
bool lol = dtble.AsEnumerable().Any(l => array[0] == l.Field<String>("id"));
```

I need to add more condition to this code because I want to check more than one conditional.

My conditional need to add in this Linq is:

`array[1] == l.Field<String>("Name")`

and

`array[2] == l.Field<String>("Stunt")`

Comment: Simple logical operator `&&`

Comment: I know it, but I don't have experience with LinQ. My bad.

Comment: can you show sample data from array and DataTable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now i got what you mean:

So you want to match the id, check if the name starts with same word in both array and DataTable and check for matching Stunt. So do the following:

```
bool lol = (from dRow in dtble.AsEnumerable()
            where array[0] == dRow.Field<string>("id")
            && GetFirstWord(array[1]) == GetFirstWord(dRow.Field<string>("Name"))
            && array[2] == dRow.Field<string>("Stunt")
            select dRow).Any();
```

And add this method:

```
// returns the first word in a string
private static string GetFirstWord(string str)
{
    return str.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
}
```

**Edit:**

You may need to replace this line :

```
&& GetFirstWord(array[1]) == GetFirstWord(dRow.Field<string>("Name"))
```

If the fixed name is the one in the dataTable (as the first word) and the name might not be the first word in the array, then use this:

```
&& dRow.Field<string>("Name").Contains(GetFirstWord(array[1]))
```

Comment: You method `GetFirstWord("Levis Get out")` will return `Levis`? If the name is: `Join Chen`. I want to get second string after Split(' ').

Comment: @VănLộc so the first word in the datatable is the name, and you need to check if any word in the array matches it ? or first word in the array and any match in the name in the datatable ? Please be specific.

Comment: @VănLộc because in your example in the comments, both sides match by the first word exactly.

Comment: I tried with this method: `array[1].StartsWith(l.Field<String>("Name").Substring(0, 7)`. Seem it working for me. But I don't know how to insert into this LinQ. Can you help me?

Comment: @VănLộc just replace this line in my query `&& GetFirstWord(array[1]) == GetFirstWord(dRow.Field<string>("Name"))` with this line : `array[1].StartsWith(dRow.Field<String>("Name").Substring(0, 7)`

Comment: @VănLộc although I don't fully understand how you're using fixed indexes in your query, which is not a good thing. in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, @user3185569. I will attention.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Logical AND (`&&`) in LINQ to combine two conditions, Then your query will be like the following:

```
bool lol = dtble.AsEnumerable().Any(l =>
                                    array[0] == l.Field<String>("id") && 
                                    array[1] == l.Field<String>("Stunt"));
```

Comment: Sorry, I get data `array` from another resource. So it not correct with `dtble`.  It similar seven characters first. I tried with `StartWith()` and `SubString()` it working. But I don't know how to add into Linq code.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that the array he means is the datatable :)

Comment: I get `array` from a website and `dtble` from another website.

`array = { 12, Luvis Going, 1 | 34, Selena not at here, 0 }`

`dtble = { 12, Levis Get out, 1 | 34, Selena Buy a coffee, she not working at here, 0 }`

Like this!

Comment: In `index = 1` of `array` and `dtble` same first name. If same first like `Levis or Selena` I will check it correct

Comment: both are looks like the same structure, Could you please include the details into the question? with sample inputs and expected output?

Comment: @VănLộc What is the logic for matching a element ? If any word in the left side is in the right hand side ?  This can't work! `12, Luvis Going` and `12, Selena Buy a coffee` would match by word `12`

Comment: @VănLộc so you wan to match the first word only ?

Comment: Mean I want like: `Regex.Replace(array1[1], @"\s+", "");` (same remove all whitespace in `dtble`).
=> `array[1].StartWith(l.Field<String>("Name").SubString(0, 5))` because I need `Levis` or `Selena`. I only write code in my mind, it will not working. I don't have many experience with LinQ.

Comment: @user3185569 Yes, you can see at `index=0` and `index = 2` is same. I will continue compare with `index = 1`. At `index = 1`, I only attention first 5 characters to compare. If it correct `lol` will return true.

Comment: @VănLộc check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
(LINQQUERY).AsEnumerable().Any(x => x.FieldName1 == (value) && x.FieldName2 == (value));
```